# Where can I find something like ".apk" in BlackBerry development?

Tags: android, blackberry, file-extension

In Android (after building), we find in the `bin` folder a file of extension `.apk`.

In my BlackBerry project, I cannot find something like the `apk`, and I want to know what is the extension for BlackBerry Java apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BlackBerry, there's more than one way to build an app.  If you're using one of the common tools to build (e.g. BlackBerry Plug-In for Eclipse, or the Legacy RIM JDE), they will generally build both.

A **.cod** file is basically RIM's version of a .zip file, that contains the entire app.  Usually, the .cod file, when unpacked, contains many more smaller .cod files inside it.  This is probably the closest thing to the .apk file for Android.

Alternately, you can install apps Over-The-Air (OTA), by using a Java application descriptor (.jad) file, which is a small text file that references the main binary app bundle.  Here's an example of a jad file:

```
MIDlet-Name: HelloBB
MIDlet-Version: 1.0.0
MIDlet-Vendor: BlackBerry Developer
MIDlet-Jar-URL: HelloBB.jar
MIDlet-Jar-Size: 26037
MicroEdition-Profile: MIDP-2.0
MicroEdition-Configuration: CLDC-1.1
MIDlet-1: ,res/img/icon.png,
RIM-MIDlet-Flags-1: 0
Manifest-Version: 1.0
RIM-COD-URL: HelloBB.cod
RIM-COD-Size: 13304
RIM-COD-Creation-Time: 1340831331
RIM-COD-Module-Name: HelloBB
RIM-COD-Module-Dependencies: net_rim_cldc,net_rim_locationapi,net_rim_bb_lbs_api_2
RIM-COD-SHA1: bf 00 66 e0 30 5d 03 8c 8a b6 00 36 cf c9 76 98 40 d2 71 d9
```

When you build with the Eclipse plug-in, I believe the default is to produce all these files under the **deliverables** directory inside your main project directory, with subdirectories under that depending on what kind of app you're building, and which OS version you're targeting.  For example:

```
$ cd deliverables/Standard/5.0.0/
$ ls
HelloBB.cod HelloBB.csl HelloBB.cso HelloBB.debug   HelloBB.jad HelloBB.jar HelloBB.rapc
```

Answer (score 5):

Blackberry have **.cod and .jad also .alx files**

You can find this in your application folder. for example My project name is "SilentProfile"

1) If you open your application folder in pc you can find following folders. see pic 1[image]

2)in this structure you can find Deliverables. click on that you can find following folders 
[image]

3)click on standard you can find this folders 
5.0.0 means my application compiled on that blackberry JDE 
[image]

4)from here you have 2 ways:

**I)you can install through desktop manager :**

Here we need two files one is .alx and .cod file
you can find it .alx bellow the 5.0.0 folder another .cod file you can find inside 5.0.0 folder 
[image]

you need to take appname.alx file and appname.cod two files only

copy that files into your desktop manage and click on that it will installed.

**II)You can install manually from you devise memory :**

this is simple way just observe above picture you can find only one appname.cod file

but if app size is more than 64kb then it will split into different parts so you need to open that file using winRar and extract those files to new folder.

also you need to copy appname.JAD file to previous folder

copy that folder into your devise memory and doble click on that appname.jad file then it will open one scrren then you have to click on download ofter successfully completion you can find your appplication icon into the blackberry application folder into your phone

you can find more information here

http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/How%20to%20prepare%20and%20deploy%20a%20BlackBerry%20Java%20Application

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BlackBerry-JDE-Plug-in-for-Eclipse-Installation-and/ta-p/446870

All the best.

Comment: #HelpMeToHelpYou
You just made my day! After searching for two days on how to compile it. For people reading this, here's a small update [Blackberry Desktop download page](http://us.blackberry.com/software/desktop/desktop-pc.html) -In Blackberry desktop software, select the "Applications" pane -When done loading files, select "Import" in the upper-right corner -Navigate to you're Workspace(details above), and select the [appname].alx file -Press the "Apply button" -It will automatically install and vòila!

Answer (score 5):

The extension for BlackBerry OS7 apps is .cod. For BlackBerry PlayBook 2.0 and BlackBerry 10 the equivalent to .apk is .bar extension.